# rTorrent show the wrong info , why?

Tags: ubuntu, rtorrent

so today I installed `rtorrent` on ubuntu
and I tried to download some files

and when I clicked to see where the file downloaded `rtorrent>info` 
it shows location like :

`./[FILENAME]`
but there's nothing in the current dir where did it download ?

**my home dir. is empty ( using server edition iso )**

keep in mind : it's out of the box experience i didn't configure any thing

Comment: why would `./` be in your home directory?

Comment: sorry i meant "current" dir. not the home

Comment: If you see the file `~/.rtorrent.rc`, the `directory.default.set` line might help. You may also right-click the download and select “Save To…” to find the directory.

Comment: I `-ls` all the items on the dir , and i didn't find the  `.rtorrent.rc` file shouldn't it be created by default ?

Answer (score 0):

Just do cat .rtorrent.rc and you will see default download directory in config file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).